# issue on free live host but not on localhost - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-7

my laravel app with mysql database works fine on my local computer using WAMP. when I upload to a free live host to test I get this message when I try to register a user to the database:

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'192.168.0.64' (using password: NO) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = jdoe@jdoe.com)**

Basically anything that has to do with accessing the database on the live site does not work.

It's like mysql is an issue.  Here is my settings:

**config/database.php:**

```
        'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'sql201.epizy.com'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('epiz_25791111_contact_db', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('epiz_25791111', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('mypassword1', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

**.env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=sql201.epizy.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=epiz_25791111_contact_db
DB_USERNAME=epiz_25791111
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks,  I figured it out. I was using the free host password instead of the Vpanel password which are different.  The database features are now accessible. Apparently this free host decides to copy the random password of the vpanel to the mysql password also.  I'm not sure if I clarified but the database was in the Vpanel not an external source.   Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 2):

Your hoster does not allow connection from external sources.

[Source](https://support.infinityfree.net/mysql/connecting-to-mysql-from-elsewhere/)

Comment: are there any free hosts that offer "allow connection from external sources."  ?

Comment: I have my own servers, so i don't have experiences with free hosters. Maybe [this one](https://remotemysql.com/)

Answer (score 1):

@Kevind at your mysql server's mysql prompt enter the following:

```
CREATE USER 'forge'@'192.168.0.64' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'forge'@'192.168.0.64' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

be sure to change PASSWORD to the password you want.

Comment: Hi Steven,  I get this error when I try that:  
SQL query:

CREATE USER 'forge'@'192.168.0.64' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword1'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: you need to login to mysql with a user that has create permissions...

Comment: well 2 things:  I created the DB on the live host phpmyadmin with user "DB_USERNAME=epiz_25796052"    but also I do not see the "Privileges" tab that phpmyadmin would have on my local computer.   What next?  Do i use epiz_25796052 ?

Comment: Could it be the web host is blocking this operation?

Comment: solution: don't use free host